# How to transfer a folder with Paramiko

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I'm trying to download a 80 MB folder from a remote server onto my local machine. I know the file paths are right and I know that the folder exists. My current working code (works on a single file) is such:

```
import paramiko

def begin():
    tran=paramiko.Transport(('dns.server.name', 22))
    tran.connect(username='**',password='**')
    sftp=paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(tran)
    sftp.get('/remote/file/path', '/local/file/path')
    sftp.close()
    tran.close()
```

I've tried adding sftp.listdir, but I'm afraid I can't find enough documentation on the subject to make it understandable or usable for me. Is there something available that looks like os.walk?

My question is - How do I download small folders via the ssh2 protocol available in paramiko?

Answer (score 2):

What I suggest instead of transferring whole folder, you should first make a temporary compressed `tar` file on server programmetically and transfer that tar file using `sftp` over network - may reduce bandwidh / will work faster and will be less error prone.